# Kiwi File Not Found Error in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, kiwi

I'm getting this error with Kiwi, installed via CocoaPods, while trying to run tests:

> ld: file not found: /Users/nick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LLNetwork-dmoptbvcttajoxfniztuqeiuyggd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LLNetwork.app/LLNetwork
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This all came about when I tried to add a separate test target to use for integration tests; I made the target, added some files, and detached it from a CMD+U build (since I only want to run integration tests occasionally), but as soon as I tried to integrate it with Kiwi things blew up.

Now my original tests, those in LLNetworkTests, are also vomiting.

I have **-ObjC -framework XCTest** in Other Linker Flags, and my Bundle Loader is $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/LLNetwork.app/LLNetwork while my test host is $(BUNDLE_LOADER).  I also have the config for the Unit Test Target pointing towards my Pods project in the workspace, per Kiwi's install guide.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker helped me resolve this, and it was something as silly as not including the lib*.a file in the Link Binary With Libraries section. Derp.